# Trouble with size of partition (too small) after cloning disk/OS from USB flash drive to SSD

Tags: partition, dd, ssd, cloning

So, I have a Chromebook with two USB ports, a 128gb USB drive with my ideal Linux set up on it (Ubuntu 18.04, i3-gaps, other specific visual customizations) and an external/portable 500gb SSD that I would like to completely transfer said setup to. It's pretty clear to me that going into developer mode on my Chromebook and using `dd` in the command line is the best way to clone my setup. And after doing so successfully using:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=sdb bs=64 conv=sync,noerror status=progress
```

I ran into a problem. I realized that the partition was exactly copied of course, but this meant that it only recognized 128gb of space on the 500gb storage device, totally defeating the purpose of transferring the disk in the first place (i.e., having almost five times as much storage space).

My question, and I assume there must be a way, is how do I go about expanding/resizing the partition, either through the use of a flag in `dd` possibly, or after the partition has been cloned to the SSD perhaps? I'm at a loss and any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
So, I've `dd`'d my drive over to the SSD for the second time after formatting it with the good ol' ext4 format. And it cloned it in the way I liked! No smaller partition keeping me from filling up the drive. But there's still a problem. Ubuntu, or more specifically Thunar and i3blocks (thus far) believe I only have 81.6GB of space left. What gives?

**UPDATE 2:**

This is what gparted is showing.

[image]

While gnome-disks says this,

[image]

and this when I try to use the resize feature. gparted says nothing in this regard as it wont let me select it's resize feature.

[image]

Any thoughts y'all?

Comment: I suggest new install. You cannot have duplicate UUIDs and if UEFI duplicate GUIDs, so cannot mount both SSD & flash drive on a reboot at same time. I suggest new clean install, and restore from your backup. Good way to test that your backup has everything you need as you still have flash drive. User settings are in /home, so just copy that. If you changed system settings in /etc you may want those. And list of installed apps. I just installed 20.10 and copied /home from 20.04 and all my settings were there. I had some in /etc I also had to update, but then 20.10 is same as 20.04 config.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your reasoning. Why would I want or even need them both mounted at the same time? I'm simply transfering from one to the other, which requires both to be unmounted. And I plan on only using my new SSD once the transfer is complete. Is there really no way to simply increase the size of the partition after cloning to a new drive? That seems crazy to me.

Comment: MBR(msdos) or gpt(GUID) partitions? Some with SSD, could only change partitions with tools from SSD vendor. If gpt, you may be able to use gdisk as you have to move backup gpt partition table which has to be at end of drive to end of drive. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/446991/gparted-claims-whole-hard-drive-is-unallocated-and-gives-warning-about-gpt-table  You asked question 6 hrs ago, and still have to try to fix issue. My new install of 20.10 to partition was 10 min. Copy of /home, mostly . files as data in another partition was fast.

Comment: GPT! But see check out my update for new info.

Comment: `gdisk` has the option to "move secondary header to the end of the disk". After that you should be able to expand the partition and the file-system. I recommend using `gparted` as it has a nice GUI.

Comment: I don't see that command anywhere when I run gdisk. Any thoughts? Is there a submenu I'm not seeing? Allso, please refer to my update! would this still be a viable solution?

Comment: dd is always an exact copy to exact copy. Any formatting in advance is ignored and now you may have two backup gpt partitions. The link in the post above has a post by Rod Smith, he is author of gdisk and gives the exact commands to use. They also are in the repairing link, but it is explained more as just updating all the tables.